# Entity Data Source DateTime Where parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an EDS that looks at a list of events with DateTimes and I would like a where parameter that looks at all events for a certain day.

I would like a where that looks like this:

```
Where="it.EventStartDateTime = @testDate"
```

but as the `EventStartDateTime` contains a time and the `testDate` is only a date they never match.

I tried

```
Where="it.EventStartDateTime.Date = @testDate"
```

but I get an error about `Date` not being in the schema(?)

I've tried

```
Where="it.EventStartDateTime Like @testDate"
```

and this doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have got around this by doing this:

```
        eventsEDS.Where = "it.EventStartDateTime >= @cDate && it.EventStartDateTime < @cDate1 "; 
        eventsEDS.WhereParameters.Add("cDate", TypeCode.DateTime, eventStartDateTime.ToShortDateString());
        eventsEDS.WhereParameters.Add("cDate1", TypeCode.DateTime, eventStartDateTime.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
```

Not ideal but it works